# Finding the average of an array of doubles from file input

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, double, average

My attempts to find a way to get the average of this array have so far been fruitless. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
    const int MAX = 100;
    double voltages[MAX];
    double average;
    ifstream thefile("c:\\voltages.txt");
        if(!thefile) 
    {
                cout<<"Error opening file"<<endl;
                system("pause");
                exit(1);
    }
        for(int count = 0; count < MAX; count++)
    {
                thefile >> voltages[count];
                cout << voltages[count++] << endl;
                average = voltages[count++]/count;
        if(count == 0 || thefile.eof())
    {
                break;
    }
    }
    cout << average;
    cout << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

voltages file is

100.8

120.4

121.4

111.9

123.4

but can have up to 100 doubles.

Comment: You're incrementing `count` 3 times per loop iteration. Are you sure that was intended? Anyway, I'd go for a vector to read the file with, and `std::accumulate` divided by the size.

Comment: why calculate the average every loop. This is wasted efficiency. Use a double for a total and divide by the counter at the end, outside the loop.

Comment: Also you're never summing the voltage values anywhere, which is a pretty important step in calculating a mean.

Comment: while (thefile.eof()) { thefile >> tmp; sum+=tmp ; cnt++ } return (cnt==0)?0: sum/cnt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the average of the numbers stored in *any* C++ container (even raw arrays), use the following approach. Take the sum and divide by the number of elements:

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.0) / (std::end(v) - std::begin(v));
```

Example code in action:

[With std::vector](http://ideone.com/Dj41ni) / 
[With raw array](http://ideone.com/nyO6Zt) (Note that only the definition of the vector / array changes!)

This code doesn't check for zero length, which produces a division by zero. This will return a `NaN` value. This case can be detected in advance by using `if (std::begin(v) == std::end(v))`. You can handle such corner cases depending on your need if you don't want to return `NaN`:

- Return a well-defined value such as `0.0`
- Throw an exception
- Print a warning and exit (essentially the same as exception but can't be caught)
- Custom error handling, for example set a boolean error variable to true

Comment: Code goes boom on a 0-length vector.

Comment: @ShaunMarko Thanks. This should be added as a corner case in individual code. Some people prefer well-defined results (like 0.0), some NaN and some exceptions. Or print a warning? I don't know what people like. I put it as a warning in the answer.

Comment: @ShaunMarko Well, *boom* might be the wrong term here. It doesn't crash the program but the expression evaluates to `NaN`, which is still "valid" and just an exceptional value.

Comment: @leemes: division by zero is undefined behavior - it might be evaluating to `NaN` for you, but it might go boom for someone else. Maybe: `(std::end(v) - std::begin(v)) ? std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.0) / (std::end(v) - std::begin(v)) : 0.0`  Also a nitpick: the expression will work only for containers that have random access iterators or for arrays.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Already thought about the problem with non-random-access iterators. Is there something like std::size or similar?

Comment: `std::distance(std::begin(v),std::end(v))`, but for non-random iterators it'll walk the sequence on each call so some caching of the result might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a better idea to have a double with a running total and then a counter and do TOTAL/COUNT for the average. No need for a vector and all that.

PS: its a better idea to use .get() instead of .eof() for fstreams since sometimes text editors add an '\n' character to the end (giving you an empty string extra iteration and possible errors).

Its also generally a bad idea to increment inside [ ] for arrays and similar. Better to use [count+1] and/or increment count outside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

use the recursive defintion for average:

```
avg_n= ((n-1)* avg_n_1 + val) / n;
```

val is the value of the nth data.
avg_n is the current average
avg_n_1 is the average of the previous itertion (average over the n-1 values)

finally the last statement in the loop:

```
avg_n_1 = avg_n;
```

This way you can calculate the average without knowing  in advance how many values you will read.